# RxJS6: Why observable Pipe operator only receives OperatorFunction and not MonoTypeOperatorFunction

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to understand the `pipe` operator of observable API:

```
 export declare class Observable<T> implements Subscribable<T> {
.......
    pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
    pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
    pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>): Observable<D>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>): Observable<E>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>): Observable<F>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>): Observable<G>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>): Observable<H>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>): Observable<I>;
.......
}
```

As you could see, all of pipe overload methods receive and `OperationFunction` type.

Lets check the filter operator API:

```
export declare function filter<T, S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number) => value is S, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, S>;
export declare function filter<T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number) => boolean, thisArg?: any): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

As you can see, you have an overload method that returns an `OperationFunction` and another that returns `MonoTypeOperatorFunction`.

I have the following questions:

- RxJS6 operators like `filter`, could only be used on `pipe` method?
- Why in filter we have a overload method that return different types but the `pipe` only receives one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> RxJS6 operators like filter, could only be used on pipe method?

Pipe methods are *[pure high-order](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44)* functions. So no, they can be used as any other method. The difference being, that if you invoke them outside of a `pipe` closure, you will lose type intellisense.

> Why in filter we have a overload method that return different types
>   but the pipe only receives one?

**Take the following with a grain of salt**

Most operators/use cases in streams involve a *transformation*, eg transforming a value *x* from a domain *X* to a value *y* from a domain *Y*. This concept is abstracted by the definition of the `OperatorFunction<X,Y>` interface.

In the case of the `filter` operator, we have a specialized case of `OperatorFunction<X,Y>`, in which the condition *X is Y and Y is X* is fulfilled, as the operation takes a value *x* from the domain *X* and transforms it into a value *y* from the same domain *X*. This special case is once again abstracted by the `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<X>` interface, which is indeed [defined as an extension](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L12) of `OperatorFunction<X,X>`.

My guess is that the `MonoTypeOperatorFunction` interface was created with 2 goals:

- *Abstract* the previously explained concept by defining a explicit interface
- *Keep* the contract of `pipe(...fn: OperatorFunction<X,Y>)` by defining this interface as an extension of `OperatorFunction`